# RCFT - Moore and Seiberg

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I have been reading the 1989 Lectures on RCFT by Moore and Seiberg - ([https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/LecturesRCFT.pdf](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/LecturesRCFT.pdf)). I had a few doubts regarding them

i)  In the second section on Chiral Vertex Operatos (CVO), when they write
\begin{equation}
<i\left|\Phi_{i, k}^{j, \beta}(z)\right| k>=\left\|\Phi_{i k}^{j}\right\| z^{-\left(\Delta_{j}+\Delta_{k}-\Delta_{i}\right)}
\end{equation}
for $\beta = | \ j >$, I believe they are defining $\Phi_{i ,k}^{j, \beta}(z)$ as an operator from $\mathcal{H}_i \to \mathcal{H}_j $ which are Verma modules and not the irreducible representations of Virasoro (i.e. $M(c,h)$ in Yellow book or $\mathcal{R}_{r,s}$ in the wiki article on Minimal model). From examples I can understand there can be cases when $\left\|\Phi_{i k}^{j}\right\|$ can be $0$, but otherwise is there anyway to fix its value ? In the equation right below in the paper, the one showing the commutation relation of $\Phi_{i ,k}^{j, \beta}(z)$ with $L_n$, is the $\Phi$ on the RHS missing its indices ?

ii) On Page 6, they are talking more generally about RCFTs,  here they have
\begin{equation}
<\alpha\left|\Phi_{i, k}^{j, \beta}(z)\right| \gamma >= t^{\alpha}_{\beta \gamma} z^{-\left(\Delta_{1}+\Delta_{j}-\Delta_{n}\right)}
\end{equation}
where $t^{\alpha}_{\beta \gamma} \in Inv(\bar{W}^{i} \otimes W^{j} \otimes W^{k})$. Can someone please define $Inv(\bar{W}^{i} \otimes W^{j} \otimes W^{k})$, and $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_n$. Further, in the paragraph below, when they talk about conjugate representations, are they talking about complex conjugate representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation).

iii) What do they mean by diagonal theory right above the first equation on Page 7 ?

Comment: Inv is the set of invariant tensors. For example, if the three irreps are spinor, spinor, vector then $\mathrm{Inv}(\psi^\alpha, \bar{\psi}_\beta, V^\mu)$ would have gamma matrices. Also, diagonal theories are ones where the primary operators are in the same representations of the left and right vertex algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $R$ is a rep then the conjugate rep $R'$ is one such that $R\otimes R'$ contains the trivial rep.